# Why does \par causes error when added within \vcenter in tkz-tab tabular

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors, line-breaking, tkz-tab

In this example I have issue with `\par` command within `tkz-tab` tabular

> ```
> ! Paragraph ended before \\tkzTabLine was complete.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \par 
> l.27 \tkzTabLine{,\vcenter{\hsize3cm $x$ \par
>                                                $f(x)$},} % <---- here
> ?
> ```

I need to add multiline text in `\tkzTabLine`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}

$\vcenter{\hsize3cm $x$ \par $f(x)$}$

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit {$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ /1}%
{$-5$,$-3$}
\tkzTabLine{,\vcenter{\hsize3cm $x$ \par  $f(x)$},} % <---- here 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\endgraf` instead of `\par` (they are the same thing, just different names).

Comment: Thank's @PhelypeOleinik why `\par`  do not work, and what is the difference  with `\endgraph` ?

Comment: as Phelype says, the only difference is that it is not called `\par`. `\par` (a blank line) is not allowed in many constructs as a means of avoiding missing closing delimiters wrecking an entire document, an error is thrown at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: It's a way of TeX detecting if you forgot a `}` in the argument of a macro (for example, define `\def\test#1{(#1)}` and then use `\test{a\par b}` or `\test{a<newline><newline>b}`, and then try `\long\def\test#1{(#1)}`). `\tkzTabLine` is defined as a short macro (that is, without the `\long` prefix), so using `\par` as the argument is an error. `\endgraf` is the same thing as `\par` (defined with `\let\endgraf=\par`), but it has a different name, so it's okay.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik please can you add an answer for the issue.

Comment: @SalimBou Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time TeX was written there wasn't too many text editors with brace-matching features to catch a `}` you forgot somewhere, so Knuth build some ways of checking if you forgot a `}` before the a macro tried to grab the rest of the input file as argument. Apart from David's favourite, `\outer`, a macro can also be short or long.

A short macro can be defined as simply as:

```
\def\test#1{(#1)}
```

but then if you forget a `}`:

```
\test{a % missing } here

boom!}
```

TeX will raise that exact same error:

```
Runaway argument?
{a 
! Paragraph ended before \test was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.3 

?
```

The same macro call would not raise that error if you defined `\test` as a long macro:

```
\long\def\test#1{(#1)}
```

However TeX's scanner does not look for something that *means* a paragraph break, it just looks for a `\par` token, so LaTeX (and also plain TeX) provides you with `\endgraf`, which is a copy of `\par` defined as:

```
\let\endgraf=\par
```

You could also trick TeX by using `\csname par\endcsname` instead, or something else that would hide the `\par` token.

---

LaTeX's `\newcommand` defines a long macro by default, so if you do `\newcommand\test[1]{(#1)}`, the example above will work. `\tkzTabLine`, however, is defined with `\newcommand*`, which does a short `\def` (perhaps there's a good reason for who wrote that package to make it short; I didn't check).

Just for completeness, if you are defining the macro yourself and you are using `xparse`, then you need the `+` modifier to make the argument long, like in:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \test {+m} {(#1)}
```

Comment: I should downvote for the `\outer` comment:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But then it would be an `\outer\downvote`, and we don't support that in LaTeX ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes I had a good reason. The code used in the macro didn't support the use of `\par` so it was better to use `\nexcommand*`. I think the right solution is to use `\parbox` as often inside a node.

Answer (score 4):

Phelype explained why `\par` is forbidden there. But there is a simpler way out.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit {$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ /1}%
{$-5$,$-3$}
\tkzTabLine{,\parbox{3cm}{$x$\\ $f(x)$},}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually compiling the code and seeing what it does is said to be a good idea ;-)

Comment: Yes it's the good way  because we can use this inside a node